# Possible bug in Z3 str.to.int

Tags: string, z3, atoi

I am experimenting with **Z3 str.to.int** to evaluate its performance.
I came across the following example which looks like a bug (reported to [GitHub/Z3Prover/z3/issues](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1334) too):

```
(declare-const si String)
(declare-const sj String)
(declare-const sk String)
(declare-const i     Int)
(declare-const j     Int)
(declare-const k     Int)

(assert (= (str.to.int si) i))
(assert (= (str.to.int sj) j))
(assert (= (str.to.int sk) (* k k)))
(assert (= (- j i) k))
(assert (> i 7422885))
(assert (< j 74228850))
(assert (< i j))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;                                                  ;
; When I remove this comment everything works fine ;
;                                                  ;
;(assert (< 135 k))                                ;
;                                                  ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(check-sat)
(get-value (si sj sk i j k))
```

Output: (**that's a bug, right?**) sj is **not** the string representation of j

```
sat
((si "74228847")
 (sj "!0!")
 (sk "1")
 (i 74228847)
 (j 74228848)
 (k 1))
```

When I remove the comment I get this **correct output**:

```
sat
((si "74228713")
 (sj "74228849")
 (sk "18496")
 (i 74228713)
 (j 74228849)
 (k 136))
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest to create an issue on GitHub instead of making a post about a possible bug on SO.

Comment: @Chrono, I'm actually not sure this is a bug. I might be missing something here?

Comment: Would be helpful if you explained in greater detail *why* you think it's a bug. What exactly is wrong, in your opinion? Moreover, I second @Chrono's answer: if it's not a bug it will simply be closed, it could be a known issue (and marked as duplicate), or it's a legit issue; in any case, the issue tracker is the appropriate place.

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff, I edited the question to specify exactly where the bug is. Following your suggestion, I (also) posted this on the Z3 GitHub repository issues. This question may be of help to new Z3 string clients, and IMHO should be kept open.

Comment: Thanks! It would also be good to link to the issue you opened (from your question).